# CSV show CRLF at end of each row in MAC but CF in Windows

Tags: php, windows, macos, csv

I am reading content from a csv file with

```
$row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) { //Reading the file
                $num = count($data);

                for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $csvData[$row][$c] = $data[$c];
                }

                $row++;
            }

            return $csvData;
            fclose($handle);
        }
```

but if I create csv on MAC at the end of each row there is **CRLF** but on windows there is only **CR** and my script read fine only for windows. How could I fix my script for MAC as well.

Comment: May be this help to you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#103276

Comment: try to use ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);